# Como Convertir ArrayList<String> a Cursor Java Android

Tags: java, android

como puedo hacer para pasar un ArrayList  a un cursor con sus campos

Comment: ¿En serio cierran esto como *demasiado amplio*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una opción sería usando **[MatrixCursor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/MatrixCursor.html)**, agregando los valores del `ArrayList` dentro del cursor.

```
MatrixCursor myMatrixCursor = new MatrixCursor(myArrayList.size());
startManagingCursor(myMatrixCursor);  
//Agrega valores de ArrayList en el Cursor.  
matrixCursor.addRow(new Object[] {myArrayList.get(0), myArrayList.get(1), myArrayList.get(2), myArrayList.get(3), ..... });
```

Despues agregamos los valores al cursor a partir del MatrixCursor creado.

```
MergeCursor mergeCursor = new MergeCursor(new Cursor[] { matrixCursor, cursor });
```

Comment: en serio le recomiendas hacer eso? primero le dices usar size() y luego get(0), get(1)... ??

Comment: size para dimensionar el MatrixCursor. Voy a editar para no tener que referencer los elementos del Array por indice.

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que puedes usar [`MatrixCursor`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/MatrixCursor.html). Es una implementación de Cursor, es mutable y se puede usar [`newRow()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/MatrixCursor.html#newRow()) para agregar nuevas filas.

Espero te sirva, disculpa que no lo haya probado.

Comment: Posible fuente: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27978533/2573335